# Is it OK for users to edit the accepted answer into their question?

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer

Sometimes I find it helpful when a user applies a solution then informs the rest by editing the question to include the answer. As SO is primarily a means of matching up questions with answers, should this behavior be encouraged or should a user leave it up to the voting mechanism to push correct answers to the top?

Comment: Such edits on questions make all the other answers irrelevant.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Answers belong in the answer section, not in the question.

If an answer is already provided in the answer section, then it just makes editing the answer into a place where it doesn't belong even more absurd, not to mention defeating the purpose of having a section for answers in the first place.

If an asker wishes to designate one of the answers as the one that helped them the most or that they used in solving their problem, they can do that by marking the answer accepted which will immediately signal to readers that it is the selected answer. For the rest of us, since we have a voting mechanism as you've mentioned, we should just leave it up to votes.

Answer (score 2):

To elaborate on the [existing answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/262807/6243352), here are further reasons not to edit an answer into the question:

- It gives unilateral preferential treatment to a single answer. Votes and trending answers determine the order. Everything wrong with [floating the accepted answer to the top](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326095/please-unpin-the-accepted-answer-from-the-top) applies to answers edited into questions.
- Users without edit privileges won't be able to easily maintain their answer if it's moved to the question.
- It creates multiple copies of information that can easily go out of sync.
- Attribution is less apparent when the answer is copied.
- Unlike editing the answer into the question, [accepting the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) is meaningful for categorization and marks the question as resolved everywhere in the site (API, search results, etc).
- It discourages visitors from looking at the answer section and considering various solutions if there's already an answer baked into the question.
- It becomes difficult to distinguish comments directed to the question and those on the edited-in answer.
- It makes the original problem and context more difficult to understand for future visitors.

---

Related:

- [Is it acceptable to answer a closed question by editing the answer into the question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/404545/is-it-acceptable-to-answer-a-closed-question-by-editing-the-answer-into-the-ques?noredirect=1&lq=1)
- [Editing potential answers into questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/319747/editing-potential-answers-into-questions)
- [How to treat an old question which had an answer edited into it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/289344/how-to-treat-an-old-question-which-had-an-answer-edited-into-it)
- [What to do when an asker answers in his own question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265218/what-to-do-when-an-asker-answers-in-his-own-question?rq=1)

Comment: I'd guess, it's just because this doesn't really add all that much except of a long wall of text. I.e. it's a very verbose, very late answer to a simple, *already solved* problem.

Comment: @cafe25 Thanks, I figured as much, but I thought I'd model it after [this incredibly useful canonical](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/6243352) which offers a comprehensive overview of why posting images is a bad idea. The existing answer in this thread doesn't really dip into most of the critical reasons, like the fact that it prioritizes one answer over all others. If this is too longwinded, it's OK to ignore it in favor of the shorter answer, but actually downvoting it seems harmful since it now looks like it's disagreement, that it's good to edit answers into questions.

Comment: Existing answer basically says "it's absurd", but apparently it's not for probably hundreds of askers I've encountered through the years, so I think more elaboration is necessary.

Comment: I don't think the problem is with people not understanding the other answer, it's a problem of people not knowing how SO works.

Comment: Right, so as I said, I point people to this thread all the time to help explain how the site works, and it seems like it needed a more canonical, comprehensive treatment, possibly making it part of the official FAQ. But apparently the community disagrees with that. Oh well.

Comment: Sometimes less is more. *"Answers belong in the answer section, not in the question."* is the answer. that's all that is needed. We don't need a book or a 10 point chart on why answers don't belong in the question, they just don't. end of story. no exceptions. No amount of clarifying this point on meta will somehow make it less likely for people to keep doing it.

Comment: @KevinB Apparently so, but at least this brought +6 on the accepted answer, so I'll call it a win anyway, since IMO the issue is far underrepresented in meta FAQs relative to the frequency of occurrence on the site. I've trimmed the answer considerably, so it's not a book any longer. That seems like a pretty fatalistic attitude about meta. Why do we bother with meta at all if it doesn't change behavior? (It probably doesn't, but can't hurt to try).

Comment: What can be changed by meta, that would actually have an effect on preventing this behavior, would be pushing for UI/UX changes to help push this information to the users who need it.

Comment: @KevinB I'm all for that, but often getting those changes starts with FAQ-style posts like this one to drum up support or establish a particular site standard.

Comment: ... This is "verbose"? I'm lucky if I can ever write a post this concise and still feel like I've given the topic the treatment it deserves. More answers on Meta should be like this - it's important to consider the consequences of policy rather than just defending what the Meta community agrees upon with deontological or aesthetic appeals.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I edited it heavily, it was pretty verbose at first.