# What to do when an asker answers in his own question with my comment?

Tags: discussion

I just commented on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43865489/unable-to-control-the-position-of-text-in-a-label-using-justify-and-anchor-comma#comment74766457_43865489) I didn't feel like it was worth pasting as an answer as it was really short and simple, so I left the comment. I went back to check if he had replied to my comment or if anyone else had seen it to find out that the OP had answered his own question with what I said in the comment. Should I just leave it as it is and accept the way its turned out or do I ask him nicely to take his down so I can post it?

I found a similar [question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265218/what-to-do-when-an-asker-answers-in-his-own-question) on meta but he wasnt one of the commenters on the question and I also had no confirmation from the OP that it worked for him so I wouldn't have known to post it as an answer.

Comment: You can always post an answer of your own, but personally I'd leave things as they are now. I write comments instead of answers, too, all the time, but in doing so one accepts the possibility that someone else will turn it into one.

Comment: Well Op of the question is a cool guy, he even tag you in the answer. For me it's a greater satisfaction than getting some rep. I mean Op read you comment, did not ignore it, understand it. And tell every one that you were right.

Comment: More or less the same question from the other side - https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments-or-extended-in-chat - convert comments into answer as wiki or just regular post.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's completely wrong of you to tell the OP to remove the answer.  They did something *beneficial* by posting it.  We *want* people to take good information from comments and move them into posts (so long as the content is appropriate cited, as is the case here).

If you want to post your own answer, then by all means, it's your content, you're more than welcome to post it yourself.

In the future, if you want to post an answer, *post an answer*.  If you want to post information that isn't actually answering the question (but is still helpful) *then* post it as a comment; if you do that you won't have this issue.