# How to treat an old question which had an answer edited into it?

Tags: discussion, questions, edits

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11871520/how-could-i-read-input-from-the-console-using-the-scanner-class) (due to a new answer bumping it) and asked myself what the real question is, because it looks like OP already knows how to read console input using the Scanner class.

So I checked the edit history to find the original question. There, you can see that [an anonymous user edited an answer into the question](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2949735) and the suggested edit was approved during the review process by two other users.

Now, I don't know how to treat this question and edit correctly.

My problem is, that in this state the question makes no sense to me. It answers itself and the provided answers seem to repeat that knowledge. On the other hand, this edit is more than two years old, so other users don't seem to have a problem with it. Especially [Jamal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1950231/jamal), who is an experienced user in my eyes, kept the edit like it was and edited other stuff instead.

So I would like to know how to treat such old edits. Should I restore the old code example and original meaning of the question, or should I keep it like it is, because it is not such a big deal?

According to this [Q&A](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262806/is-it-ok-for-users-to-edit-the-accepted-answer-into-their-question), I (or someone else) should restore the old code example, to make it clear that OP didn't know how to read user input from the console, right?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it OK for users to edit the accepted answer into their question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262806/is-it-ok-for-users-to-edit-the-accepted-answer-into-their-question)

Comment: @gnat this question asks for advice on how to deal with these questions and what to do when confronted with them. The duplicate suggestion asks specifically whether it should be done in the first place and offers no real advice/guidance from the community on what to do in this ( unpoliceable ) situation.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Ideally you should roll it back. Though in this case it is a bit of mess due to the edit history. It would be take a little bit of effort to sort it out, but ultimately it would be useful.

If the edit really is the answer then you could post it as an answer yourself - making it CW if you don't want to earn reputation from it.

I suspect that the later editors didn't realise that the edit was the answer.

Comment: Well, in this case I would create a new edit to re-insert the original code. I guess, a real rollback is not sufficient here. And luckily there are some good answers already, so I don't need to add one, but I keep that in mind if I find another question with an inserted answer. Thank you.