# Is it better to answer or edit your question to post solution?

Tags: discussion, self-answer

If someone figures out a solution to their own question, is it better to answer their own question and accept it (provided that no one else gave the correct solution) or is it better to update the original question with solution?

What are the trade-offs and etiquette regarding this?

Comment: If I spot a title edited to "[Solved] - (original title)", I *immediately* roll it back. How many questions "solved" this way  did you find on SO?

Comment: Related: [Editing self-answer out of question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/278050/3524344)

Comment: Related: [How to treat an old question which had an answer edited into it?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/289344/3524344)

Comment: Related: [Is it OK for users to edit the accepted answer into their question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/262806/3524344)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Answers to questions should be posted as answers. It's perfectly OK to answer your own question, but the question should only contain the question, not an answer to the question (*which would be noise*).

Answer (score 1):

If you edit a question to include an answer, then it is no longer a question.  It becomes a statement.

Logically, it should then be closed as Very Low Quality and/or Unclear What You're Asking.

So, no, don't edit the answer into the question - post an answer.

Comment: Its not unintelligible garbage, so VLQ would not be a good fit.

Comment: ... You can't close something because it's VLQ...