# What should be done to questions OP solves themselves without posting an answer?

Tags: discussion, questions, answers

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77186139/why-i-cant-print-a-vector-or-matrix) particular question, the OP solves the problem on his own for which the question was asked. You can read the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77186139/why-i-cant-print-a-vector-or-matrix#comment136072781_77186139) to see them mentioning:

> Thanks, I found the way to compile it correctly, all the problem was in ...

I do not have many examples like this, but I'm sure many of you have encountered such an event when the OP solves the issue without posting an answer.

What should be done to the solved questions (without an answer) like this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can post an answer. If you know how they did it, you can try to recreate their solution and post an answer for them or you can come up with your own solution.

However, if OP says they discovered a problem in an unrelated part of the software that wasn't part of the question, or if it turned out to be a simple typo, you should vote to close the question as unreproducible.

Comment: What should be done in cases like this: [Ambiguous overload between int32_t or int64_t parameters when passing long](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10579544/5740428)? OP has posted their full solution in the question itself instead of an answer. I doubt that they will bother to update their old question, and it would be plagiarism if I just ripped their solution and posted it as an answer. Even if I posted my own version of that answer, with my own alterations, it would conflict with the author's intent to remove theirs from the question.

Comment: Thanks for coming up with a satisfactory answer! I have a question in my mind. Is it a good practice to answer the questions when the OP potentially no longer needs it? I'm talking about questions like they are not really helpful to others. Answers to questions like this usually don't get upvotes.

Comment: @Jan Answers do not belong in questions. The "solution" needs to be edited out. [How to treat an old question which had an answer edited into it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/289344/how-to-treat-an-old-question-which-had-an-answer-edited-into-it)

Comment: @JanSchultke You can roll it back and post the solution as a community answer, mentioning the attribution. E.g. [NodeRed to MongoDB operation with a Javascript object](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77183626/1839439)

Comment: @RohanBari We don't care whether OP needs it or not. We do not post answers just for their benefit. They do not post questions just so only they can get the answer. It doesn't matter whether they need the solution or not. If you think the answer is not useful, you don't have to add it. But the whole point of having answers is so that others can see the solution.

Comment: @yivi and Dharman, thanks for the advice. I have done as suggested: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77187605/5740428