# Add description of used solution - how?

Tags: support, asking-questions

I want to reply back what solution was used. The substance is that an answer often has the core of the idea solving the problem but is often not ready for direct use and thus (a) needs to be packaged and (b) often can be polished a little more.

A soft benefit I seek in this - when I search for solutions - is to get some feedback and summary from the person asking and working out the solution. That is also why I like this to be added. The person asking has often invested the most and has the most recent learning experience to share.

How do I write about what solution I went with and how it was done to my own question? And this within the rules of stackoverflow? I did this over a year ago and someone yesterday rolled back that edit (which seems somewhat odd to me, but ok, I guess its part of the system).

"Policy question" that made the moderator user rollback my edit:
[Is it OK for users to edit the accepted answer into their question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262806/is-it-ok-for-users-to-edit-the-accepted-answer-into-their-question)

Thanks beforehand for any suggestions and comments.

Comment: Please read [Can I answer my own question?](http://superuser.com/help/self-answer)

Comment: Just to be clear, I am not one of SO's team of elected moderators. Roll back is a community moderation ability available to any user with 2,000 reputation or more on SO. Elected moderators will have a diamond following their display name and there is an official list in the site's user tab.

Comment: @Air, ah, ok, understood. I will just leave the question as is for now, let me know if you see a problem with that.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to show the world what solution you used that is what the little green check mark next to the answer is for:

[image: answer with check mark]

Not only does that check mark tell the world that this is the solution that help you the most but it also gives the person who answered your question 15 reputation.  If you use someone else's answer to come up with your own better answer then you can post your own answer.  In cases like that you should attribute in your answer what user/answer you used to get your answer.

Comment: @BillWoodger That is exactly what happened.  Thanks for pointing it out.  I fixed it.

Comment: Tidying away then. Thanks.

Comment: Also a side effect which is probably relevant to this question: the accepted answer automatically rises to the top currently - if its not a self-answered question. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/283456/order-highest-upvoted-answer-before-accepted-answer

Comment: And if you want to answer your own question with additional packaging/polishing/whatever don't forget to credit the original answer that helped you. You can still accept that answer and add you own answer.

Comment: Thanks @NathanOliver for the reply - although I do think I understand the green checkbox to "show the world what solution you used" . I did use it to denote the answer I used - that was not really what I was after in asking my question on adding a description or report of used solution.

Answer (score 2):

So the answer is to: Add description/report of implemented solution as your own answer, do not edit it into original question.

Thanks for the discussion and to @DavidPostill for the useful link and @Gimby for the related discussion.

Comment: Iä'm not going to mark my own answer as used, it does not seem "right". Despite the system.