# Editing potential answers into questions

Tags: discussion, rollback-wars

**tldr;** Is it okay to edit answers into questions?

---

A user asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36223766/2069064), then added a good clarifying example of what was intended. When OP received an answer suggestion in the comments, OP then edited a solution based off of that suggestion into the question.

I'm of the view that answers belong in the answer section, so I rolled back that last edit. And then I rolled back a subsequent OP edit when he added it again. But now OP rolled it back *again* and is very strongly insisting on keeping the answer in the question (emphasis in original):

> Enough is enough. **STOP EDITING THIS QUESTION**. Edit your own answer if you feel like editing something. But keep your hands to your own stuff. Thank you

I think that's kinda bullshit, but the fact that OP has 90k rep gives me pause. Moreover, a 300k user proffered:

> i always see the advice to askers that they post "what I have tried so far". I think alf is showing what he tried so far, based on user-comment input.

But I don't see how that's related to this case either - given that the edit was, again, a solution to the question - and not a failed attempt at one.

Comment: @gnat It's not the accepted answer that was edited into the question.

Comment: Answers don't belong in questions.  They make the question hard to understand.  All the meta content (like Edit 1) is also noise.  Unfortunately, since the other user is rolling the changes back, it's tough to fix the problems.  Flag for a moderator and explain the situation.

Comment: "edit was, again, a solution to the question" - that qualifies as answer and, since asker apparently considered it as such, qualifies it as accepted one

Comment: I think removing it is the correct action here, but that we don't lose the value of the answer you can post it as cw-answer.

Comment: @Rizier123 I like the cw-answer idea, did that.

Comment: I don't understand the problem.  Copypasta the orignal down and add in the changes to the copy, along with a suitable, 'after adding in @Fred fixes', note', so leaving the original code untouched.  Why do posters have to make things so difficult?

Comment: Did you mean "Is it okay to edit questions into answers?"? I thought you complained that alf changed his question by edits and made it into an answer.

Comment: Vote for reopen because it is not a dupe. Neither was my comment an answer (not even one in disguise), nor was it accepted.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb I meant that Alf edited the question in order to add an answer into it.

Comment: This may be ok to point out that a certain approach is not applicable, but this doesn't seem to be the case here...

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4324763/c-can-we-have-functions-inside-functions which i just made to conform to this aswell

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You are correct that answers shouldn't be edited into the question, but incorrect to get into an edit war with the OP and roll the edit back after the first time.

Once the author knew they shouldn't be editing their answer into the question and continued to do it anyway, the only course of action you have is to flag the post for a mod, explain the situation, and let them deal with it.  They have tools to deal with someone vandalizing their own post, and you don't.

Comment: Isn't there an automatic flag for such behavior?

Comment: @RadLexus The mod isn't fagged when there is an edit, a rollback, and then another edit made.  Given that the rollback war in this case went on *well* beyond that, they would be a flag, yes, but this user *should* have flagged the post before the auto mod flag would have happened.  The idea is to flag the mod *before a rollback war starts* rather than *starting a rollback war* and flagging a mod after the fact.

Comment: The alleged "answer" isn't an answer that would be accepted by me. It's just a sketch of one possible answer, but important to know about for readers. I would accept a full answer from Johannes, who came up with the idea. Of course the question text is the right place to have all the relevant information about the question. Such information does *not* belong in answers.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf The fact that you think it's a bad, or incomplete, answer doesn't mean it should be edited into the question.  The fact that you specifically say, when editing it into the question, that it's an answer, and state that it works, means that it very clearly is an answer, even if it wouldn't be a *good* answer as it sits.  It's not adding information to the question; it's asserting that you no longer *have* a question.