# How best to deal with self-answers edited into questions?

Tags: discussion, questions, answers

Prompted by the recent meta post regarding [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64287048/is-it-possible-to-construct-a-java-stream-expression-to-return-a-2d-boolean-arra).

The asker has edited their question to include the answer they found themselves. This is against Stack Overflow rules, which are to self-answer your own question. The asker appears to be ignoring comments requesting them to comply with this rule.

My instinct, then, is to fix this by editing the question to strip out the self-answer, and move it to proper answer. This is problematic because of course I will be credited with any rep for that answer, as opposed to the asker who technically "owns" that answer. (To be clear: I don't care about rep, I'm not in this for farming, just want to make the question and answer conform with the rules.) Not to mention licensing.

I'm not sure what else can be done here: AFAIK mods cannot change the attribution of a post, so even if I mod-flag the question they cannot rectify this situation (if they edit/post the self-answer it will obviously be attributed to them, which is the same issue as if I did it. I don't know if it's possible to use the Community user instead, but I still feel like that's "ripping off" the asker who has answered their own question, and once more the issue is one of correct attribution. (OTOH, the asker hasn't bothered to come back and do the right thing by posting a self-answer, so it could be argued they have effectively abandoned the question and we are free to fix it up as we see fit).

Suggestions?

Comment: You could post as Community Wiki Answer.

Comment: Related (but probably not a dupe): https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/319747/4014959 But also see this question on MSE, which more closely addresses your concerns: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/74101/334566

Comment: My personal opinion is rollback the edit (perhaps edit the old version, so that you can add notes in reason, as you can't with a simple rollback) and then leave a comment stating why you rolled it back, and that the OP needs to post an answer. If the OP readds the answer to the question, rather than getting into an edit "war" then raise a custom flag.

Comment: @PM2Ring Thanks for that - I did a Google for "site:meta.stackoverflow.com" which of course didn't find the second link :facepalm:. We really need a centralised searchable DB for these types of questions.

Comment: No worries. A good rule of thumb is to search MSE first if it's an issue that's likely to affect most sites in the network. Also, there are some questions on MSE from before the MSE / MSO split that didnt get migrated to MSO because they're applicable to multiple sites, even though they were originally written with Stack Overflow in mind.

Comment: "Ignoring" is a big word, my personal assumption is that said user simply doesn't notice it because they don't really interact with stack overflow until they personally need something. Their question was (self-)answered, their meta post was resolved, they moved on. But bonus points to you that you did not let it sleep like I was planning to do :)

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to [@PM 2Ring](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/4014959/pm-2ring) for linking me to [What to do when OP answers his/her own question in an edit?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/74101/334566) which seems to answer this question from the behaviour side.

However I am more interested in the legal side of the equation, so I've posted a new question on Meta.SE regarding exactly that, since Meta.SE seems to be the more appropriate forum:

[Is moving self-answers in questions into separate answers under the Community user valid under CC BY-SA?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/355302/is-moving-self-answers-in-questions-into-separate-answers-under-the-community-us)